# Can the contents of an AMQ topic be viewed somehow?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to view the contents of a topic using `activemq-admin`.

This is what I'm trying:

```
./activemq-admin browse --amqurl tcp://localhost:61616 my.topic
```

This is what I get as output:

```
Java Runtime: Sun Microsystems Inc. 1.6.0_24 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre
Heap sizes: current=62848k  free=62190k  max=932096k
JVM args: -Dactivemq.classpath=/home/pc/dev/apache-activemq-5.3.1/conf; -Dactivemq.home=/home/pc/dev/apache-activemq-5.3.1 -Dactivemq.base=/home/pc/dev/apache-activemq-5.3.1
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /home/pc/dev/apache-activemq-5.3.1
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /home/pc/dev/apache-activemq-5.3.1
```

Which is not what I want. I want to see the messages in the queue in raw form somehow. Is that possible ?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - but i can confirm that i can't see the contents of a topic at http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp though when i go to http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp i can navigate to contents of messages which haven't been dequeued. Don't know why that is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot browse the contents of topics due to the nature of what a topic is. Messages are sent in, and if there are any subscribers, each receives a message at that point in time. Messages are generally not retained (with some exceptions that aren't relevant here).

However, sometimes for debugging purposes it's useful to see messages that were sent to a topic. The easiest way to do so is to set up a [virtual destination](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html), that copies each message sent to the topic into a queue.

```
<destinationInterceptors>
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
            <compositeTopic name="events" forwardOnly="false">
                <forwardTo>
                    <queue physicalName="events.thatHaveHappened" />
                </forwardTo>
            </compositeTopic>
        </virtualDestinations>
    </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

You can then browse the queue via JMX or the web console.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the content of the messages in the Queue using the [web console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html)

[image]

Comment: How ? I can see the number of messages produced/consumed, but not the exact messages.

Comment: Are you able to view http://<yourhost>:<port>/admin/ ? Then navigate to Queues (in the menu), click on one of the Queue names and then on one of the messages. See screen shot added above.

Comment: Oh I saw your other comment now sorry. Yes I can also see the contents of the queues, but not the topics (and I need the topics). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This third-party tool lets you subscribe to topics and inspect the messages to a topic:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/activemqbrowser/

Connect to the server, then subscribe to the topic you want. It worked OK for me to look at the message details and payloads.